# How to think about styling AngularJS components?

Tags: css, angularjs, components

I'm working on an AngularJS project with the aim of slowly getting things in order for Angular 6, or whatever version is out when we start on the upgrade. One of the big pieces of that work is converting existing directives into components.

The thing I'm struggling the most with, is that every instance of a component introduces an extra element into the DOM that wraps my actual component HTML and breaks the hierarchy, making it very hard to write CSS that does what it needs to.

To illustrate my dilemma, imagine a simple component called `alert` that provides styling for various types of messages you want a user to pay attention to. It accepts two bindings, a `message` and a `type`. Depending on the `type` we will add some special styling, and maybe display a different icon. All of the display logic should be encapsulated within the component, so the person using it just has to make sure they are passing the data correctly and it will work.

```
<alert message="someCtrl.someVal" type="someCtrl.someVal"></alert>
```

### Option A: put styling on a `<div>` inside the extra element

**Component template**

```
<div
    class="alert"
    ng-class="{'alert--success': alert.type === 'success', 'alert--error': alert.type === 'error'}">
    <div class="alert__message">{{alert.message}}</div>
    <a class="alert__close" ng-click="alert.close()">
</div>
```

**Sass**

```
.alert {

    & + & {
        margin-top: 1rem; // this will be ignored
    }

    &--success {
        background-color: green; // this will work
    }

    &--error {
        background-color: red; // this will work
    }
}
```

This works fine as long as the component is completely ignorant of everything around it, but the second you want to put it inside a flex-parent, or use a selector like "+", it breaks.

### Option B: try to style the extra element directly

**Component template**

```
<div class="alert__message">{{alert.message}}</div>
<a class="alert__close" ng-click="alert.close()">
```

**Sass**

```
alert {

    & + & {
        margin-top: 1rem; // this will work now
    }

    .alert--success {
        background-color: green; // nowhere to put this
    }

    .alert--error {
        background-color: red; // nowhere to put this
    }
}
```

Now I have the opposite problem, because I have nowhere to attach my modifier classes for the success and error states.

Am I missing something here? What's the best way to handle the presence of this additional element which sits above the scope of the component itself?

Comment: So the issue is that your sibling selector won't work because you end up with a structure like `<alert><div class='alert'></div></alert>`? Or was that just one example of many styling issues?

Comment: Sibling is one example. Another bad one is if the component is a flex-child, it will break the flex-tree and cause all different types of layout issues depending on what flex properties are applied.

Comment: Would using using `transclude: true` on your component work? That would make it so that the `<alert></alert>` element is completely replaced with the contents of your component template.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do option A. This allows you to easily identify and create specific styles for your components without fear that they will overwrite site-wide styles. For instance, I'll use nested styles to accomplish this:

```
#componentContainer {
    input[type=text] {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to make generic styles for your component that won't spill out into the rest of your solution.